What can I use iTerm2's Profiles feature for?
I basically use iTerm2 Profiles as the connection management for SSH, each profile manages a SSH connection. What other use cases do profiles have besides SSH management?
I googled iTerm2 profiles but I couldn't find any useful information. iTerm2's own feature list does describe SSH as the Profile feature's use case:


I start different shells e.g. fish, xonsh in different profiles - also start some shells with different fonts when I want to run tasj=ks with much output. Also you could run some programs directly

Generally, profiles are useful for anything where you would want to easily switch between a group of settings - different SSH connections is one case where you might want this, but there are many others...

iTerm2 has a "Hotkey Window" feature that I use regularly:


A dedicated hotkey window is a window that is associated with a profile and has a hotkey attached to it. By pressing the hotkey, the window opens or closes [...] In its simplest form, it's a system-wide terminal window that you can open with a hotkey.

(emphasis mine)
You can create multiple Hotkey Window profiles, each with their own hotkey to trigger them, as well as their own preferences (where they should appear on the screen, colours, fonts, etc).

There is an Automatic Profile Switching feature that automatically switches the profile of the current window in response to specified rules. This means that you could use different profiles as a way to change the colour/font/other visual settings of your terminal when running certain jobs, in certain directories, etc.

Under Profiles > [profile name] > General > Command in the iTerm2 settings, it's possible to send text at the beginning of a session in a specific profile. This can be used for a variety of things, like automatically running a command when the profile is opened, or sourcing specific environment variables for a certain task. Combined with the Hotkey Window feature, this can be very powerful.



This is admittedly an edge use case, however I have different terminal windows with different sounds configured for the terminal bell, so that when they alert I know which one is triggering.

That is an interesting use case. Part of reason I asked my question is I now use warp more often than iTerm2. But warp lacks of ssh management. That is the main reason I still use iTerm2. So other than this, what do profiles provide us. Before using warp I didn't give much of thought to it.
